# Save object in Session on a ashx handler and get the object in another ashx handler. How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, httpcontext, ashx

I have two handlers.

In Authentication.ashx Handler i save a object on session like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionUserSession"] = userCache;
```

Then, i have another Handler, Send.ashx and i want to get the object saved in Authentication.ashx.

How i do that? 
My code to get the object is:

```
UserCache userCache = (UserCache) HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionUserSession"];
```

The problem:
userCache is allways null, and i have IRequiresSessionState implemented on both handlers.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is on Send.ashx. The variable userCache is allways null. And i have the interface IRequiresSessionState implemented on both Handlers.

Comment: What client technology is used to access this?

Comment: What kind of object is Connection? It is bad practice to put any non-agile objects in the Session (objects that hold resources like DB connections, open file handles, etc.).

Comment: How does execution pass from one handler to the other? Is the session id cookie being correctly preserved?

Comment: So, i have two aspx Pages. In Default.aspx i call Authentication.ashx and save the object UserCache in Session. I return to Default.aspx, go to SecondPage.aspx and make another call to Send.ashx. On Send.ashx i want get the value saved in session to get UserCache.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they mean is in Authentication.ashx:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Session["ConnectionUserSession"] = userCache;
}
```

And in Send.ashx,

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    UserCache userCache = (UserCache) context.Session["ConnectionUserSession"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the line

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionUserSession"] = userCache;
```

is not executed, or the string keys used for saving and retrieval are different, or you have a call to

```
Session.Abandon();
```

between these two handlers.